# Crop shadowed multiline text

Tags: html, css

There is shadowed multiline text, but it's height is supposed to be cropped to show only 3 lines of it:

```
<h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer</p></h1>
<style>
h1 {
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 1em;
  max-height: 4em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1 p {
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
}
</style>
```

As it can be seen [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4RUJcULMlUHsEH5t2fRz?p=preview), text shadow is being cropped too, and the desired result would be to crop text but not its shadow.

Real text is already being truncated, but if it will be truncated to cover worst case scenario ('MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM...'), it will be truncated too much.

Can this be solved with CSS alone? What are the options here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A left padding on `h1` will fix this

```css
h1 {
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-size: 200%;
  max-height: 4em;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

h1 p {
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
}
```

```html
<h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer</p></h1>
```

---

If one need to match this element's vertical alignment with previous and subsequent content, add a negative margin to compensate for the padding

```css
h1 {
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-size: 200%;
  max-height: 4em;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

h1 p {
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
}
```

```html
<h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer</p></h1>
```

Comment: So I guess, in order to keep the text in the same place we should procide negative margin plus positive padding?

Comment: @estus If you need to match this element's vertical alignment with previous and subsequent content, yes. Updated my answer with that info.